# How to redirect and append both standard output and standard error to a file with Bash

Tags: bash, append, stdout, io-redirection, stderr

To redirect [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) to a truncated file in Bash, I know to use:

```
cmd > file.txt
```

To redirect standard output in Bash, appending to a file, I know to use:

```
cmd >> file.txt
```

To redirect both standard output and [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) to a truncated file, I know to use:

```
cmd &> file.txt
```

How do I redirect both standard output and standard error appending to a file? `cmd &>> file.txt` did not work for me.

Comment: I would like to note that &>outfile is a Bash (and others) specific code and not portable. The way to go portable (similar to the appending answers) always was and still is >outfile 2>&1

Comment: … and ordering of that is important.

Comment: If you care about the ordering of the content of the two streams, see @ed-morton 's answer to a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406028/redirect-to-a-file-stdout-first-and-then-stderr/56407419#56407419).

Answer (score 2552, accepted):

```
cmd >>file.txt 2>&1
```

Bash executes the redirects from left to right as follows:

1. `>>file.txt`: Open `file.txt` in append mode and redirect `stdout` there.
2. `2>&1`: Redirect `stderr` to *"where `stdout` is currently going"*. In this case, that is a file opened in append mode. In other words, the `&1` reuses the file descriptor which `stdout` currently uses.

Comment: works great! but is there a way to make sense of this or should I treat this like an atomic bash construct?

Comment: It's simple redirection, redirection statements are evaluated, as always, from left to right.

>>file : Red. STDOUT to file (append mode) (short for 1>>file)
2>&1   : Red. STDERR to "where stdout goes"

Note that the interpretion "redirect STDERR to STDOUT" is wrong.

Comment: It says "append output (stdout, file descriptor 1) onto file.txt and send stderr (file descriptor 2) to the same place as fd1".

Comment: @TheBonsai however what if I need to redirect STDERR to another file but appending? is this possible?

Comment: if you do `cmd >>file1 2>>file2` it should achieve what you want.

Comment: if pipe is what you want, try `cmd1 |& cmd2`. It works in bash v4+.

Comment: Just to emphasize this to users like myself: the order of the redirect matters, 2>&1 should be after >>file.txt.

Comment: I have file1.txt and file2.txt in currect directory. When I run: 
1.  ls file{1..5}.txt 1>res.txt 2>&1: it gives correct output to res.txt
But when I write
2.  ls file{1..5}.txt 1>res.txt 2>res.txt: now it doesn't give correct output to res.txt, here in res.txt some output is omitted compare to what it should've been if we weren't redirect any stream.
Why ?

Comment: Much punctuation makes this syntax difficult. You may be familiar with file descriptor `1` = `stdout` and `2` = `stderr`. `stdout` is the default (over `stderr`) and therefore comes first. It is necessary to put the `2` before the `>` when redirecting `stderr` because otherwise as soon as `>` is encountered it will be interpreted as redirecting `stdout`. Your programming experience may help you remember `&` as a reference character, so `&1` is something like "pointer to 1". Hopefully this breakdown provides some mnemonic hooks that can assist in recollection without making another SO search ;)

Answer (score 491):

There are two ways to do this, depending on your Bash version.

The classic and portable (**Bash pre-4**) way is:

```
cmd >> outfile 2>&1
```

A nonportable way, starting with **Bash 4** is

```
cmd &>> outfile
```

(analog to `&> outfile`)

For good coding style, you should

- decide if portability is a concern (then use the classic way)
- decide if portability even to Bash pre-4 is a concern (then use the classic way)
- no matter which syntax you use, don't change it within the same script (confusion!)

If your script already starts with `#!/bin/sh` (no matter if intended or not), then the Bash 4 solution, and in general any Bash-specific code, is not the way to go.

Also remember that Bash 4 `&>>` is just shorter syntax — it does not introduce any new functionality or anything like that.

The syntax is (beside other redirection syntax) described in the [Bash hackers wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#appending_redirected_output_and_error_output).

Comment: I prefer &>> as it's consistent with &> and >>. It's also easier to read 'append output and errors to this file' than 'send errors to output, append output to this file'. Note while Linux generally has a current version of bash, OS X, at the time of writing, still requires bash 4 to manually installed via homebrew etc.

Comment: I like it more because it is shorter and only tweoi places per line, so what would for example zsh make out of "&>>"?

Comment: Also important to note, that in a cron job, you have to use the pre-4 syntax, even if your system has Bash 4.

Comment: @zsero cron doesn't use bash at all... it uses `sh`. You can change the default shell by prepending `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the `crontab -e` file.

Comment: `&>>` and `&>` are **both** Bash extensions and so less portable; the "consistent" approach would be to avoid both.

Answer (score 121):

In Bash you can also explicitly specify your redirects to different files:

```
cmd >log.out 2>log_error.out
```

Appending would be:

```
cmd >>log.out 2>>log_error.out
```

Comment: Redirecting two streams to the same file using your first option will cause the first one to write "on top" of the second, overwriting some or all of the contents.  Use ***cmd >> log.out 2> log.out*** instead.

Comment: Thanks for catching that; you're right, one will clobber the other.  However, your command doesn't work either.  I think the only way to write to the same file is as has been given before `cmd >log.out 2>&1`.  I'm editing my answer to remove the first example.

Comment: The reason `cmd > my.log 2> my.log` doesn't work is that the redirects are evaluated from left to right and `> my.log` says "create new file `my.log` replacing existing files and redirect `stdout` to that file" and *after* that has been already done, the `2> my.log` is evaluated and it says "create new file `my.log` replacing existing files and redirect `stderr` to that file". As UNIX allows deleting open files, the stdout is now logged to file that used to be called `my.log` but has since been deleted. Once the last filehandle to that file is closed, the file *contents* will be also deleted.

Comment: On the other hand, `cmd > my.log 2>&1` works because `> my.log` says "create new file `my.log` replacing existing files and redirect `stdout` to that file" and after that has been already done, the `2>&1` says "point file handle 2 to file handle 1". And according to POSIX rules, file handle 1 is always stdout and 2 is always stderr so `stderr` then points to already opened file `my.log` from first redirect. Notice that syntax `>&` doesn't create or modify actual files so there's no need for `>>&`. (If *first* redirect had been `>> my.log` then file had been simply opened in append mode.)

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen `>` creates a new file _if it doesn't already exist_; otherwise it truncates an existing file. The reason that `cmd > my.log 2> my.log` does not work as expected has almost nothing to do with the fact that the file is truncated twice (because both of those occur before `cmd` starts), and everything to do with the two streams having independent output cursors, so that whichever writes a given byte _last_ wins _for that byte_. On the other hand, using `>>` means that every write goes to the _current_ end of file.

Comment: The `>` doesn't check if the file exists. It simply uses flags `O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT` for `open()` and the kernel takes care of the rest: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3b6bd19457e260b65d11f2712ec3da56cef463f/make_cmd.c#L711

Answer (score 105):

This should work fine:

```
your_command 2>&1 | tee -a file.txt
```

It will store all logs in *file.txt* as well as dump them in the terminal.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to see the output in the terminal, too. However, this was not the question originally asked.

Comment: tee with pipe take lot more time than direct redirection. It works but slowly, with more memory used and extrat thread

Answer (score 76):

In Bash 4 (as well as [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`) 4.3.11):

```
cmd &>> outfile
```

just out of box.

Comment: @mikemaccana: [TheBonsai's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/876267/4279) shows bash 4 solution since 2009

Comment: Why does this answer even exist when it's included in TheBonsai's answer? Please consider deleting it. You'll get a [disciplined badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-disciplined-badge).

Answer (score 35):

Try this:

```
You_command 1> output.log  2>&1
```

Your usage of `&> x.file` does work in Bash 4. Sorry for that: (

### Here comes some additional tips.

0, 1, 2, ..., 9 are file descriptors in bash.

0 stands for [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)), 1 stands for [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), 2 stands for [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)). 3~9 is spare for any other temporary usage.

Any file descriptor can be redirected to other file descriptor or file by using operator `>` or `>>`(append).

Usage:
<**file_descriptor**> **>** <**filename** | **&file_descriptor**>

Please see the reference in *[Chapter 20. I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)*.

Comment: Your example will do something different than the OP asked for: It will redirect the stderr of `You_command` to stdout and the stdout of `You_command` to the file `output.log`. Additionally it will not append to the file but it will overwrite it.

Comment: Correct: ***File descriptor*** could be any values which is more than 3 for all other files.

Comment: Your answer shows the most common output redirection error: redirecting STDERR to where STDOUT is currently pointing and only after that redirecting STDOUT to file. This will not cause STDERR to be redirected to the same file. Order of the redirections matters.

Comment: does it mean, i should firstly redirect STDERROR to STDOUT, then redirect STDOUT to a file.

`1 > output.log  2>&1`

Comment: @Quintus.Zhou Yup. Your version redirects err to out, and at the same time out to file.

Comment: Re *"does work in..."*: Do you mean *"does* ***not*** *work in..."* (the opposite)?

Answer (score 21):

## Some remarks and useful tricks

#### Introduction

From [What does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283739/1765658), I will use in this answer the command:

```
ls -ld /tmp /tnt
```

for populating simultaneously both *`STDIN`* and *`STDERR`*. (In the hope you don't have any *entry* in your *root*, called `tnt`.)

### Redirections from script himself

You could plan redirections from the script itself:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

exec 1>>logfile.txt
exec 2>&1

/bin/ls -ld /tmp /tnt
```

Running this will create/append `logfile.txt`, containing:

```
/bin/ls: cannot access '/tnt': No such file or directory
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Apr  5 11:20 /tmp
```

Or

```bash
#!/bin/bash

exec 1>>logfile.txt
exec 2>>errfile.txt

/bin/ls -ld /tmp /tnt
```

While create or append *standard output* to `logfile.txt` and create or append *errors output* to `errfile.txt`.

### Log to many different files

You could create two different logfiles, appending to one *overall* log and recreating another *last* log:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e lastlog.txt ] ;then
    mv -f lastlog.txt lastlog.old
fi
exec 1> >(tee -a overall.log /dev/tty >lastlog.txt)
exec 2>&1

ls -ld /tnt /tmp
```

Running this script will

- if `lastlog.txt` already exist, rename them to `lastlog.old` (overwriting `lastlog.old` if they exist).
- create a new `lastlog.txt`.
- append everything to `overall.log`
- output everything to the terminal.

### Simple *and* combined logs

```bash
#!/bin/bash

[ -e lastlog.txt ] && mv -f lastlog.txt lastlog.old
[ -e lasterr.txt ] && mv -f lasterr.txt lasterr.old

exec 1> >(tee -a overall.log combined.log /dev/tty >lastlog.txt)
exec 2> >(tee -a overall.err combined.log /dev/tty >lasterr.txt)

ls -ld /tnt /tmp
```

So you have

- `lastlog.txt` last run log file
- `lasterr.txt` last run error file
- `lastlog.old` previous run log file
- `lasterr.old` previous run error file
- `overall.log` appended overall log file
- `overall.err` appended overall error file
- `combined.log` appended overall error and log combined file.
- still output to the terminal

#### Same, using *timestamped log filenames*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sTime=${EPOCHSECONDS}
for pre in log err; do
   printf -v ${pre}file '%s-%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T-%08x.txt' "$pre" "$sTime" $$
done

exec 1> >(tee -a overall.log combined.log /dev/tty >"$logfile")
exec 2> >(tee -a overall.err combined.log /dev/tty >"$errfile")

ls -ld /t{nt,mp}
```

- I use `$sTime` in order to ensure both file will present exactly **same** timestamp. (If `$EPOCHSECONDS` is invoked two times, they could differ between each expansion!)
- I add formed 8 characters hexadecimal representation of *currend pid*: `$$` in order to ensure unicity.

after 3rd run, you must found 9 files:

```
ls -ltr
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   49 19 nov 10:36 log-20231119103611-00120649.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   73 19 nov 10:36 err-20231119103611-00120649.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   73 19 nov 10:36 err-20231119103634-001207b8.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   49 19 nov 10:36 log-20231119103634-001207b8.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  147 19 nov 10:40 overall.log
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  219 19 nov 10:40 overall.err
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   49 19 nov 10:40 log-20231119104000-001216f0.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   73 19 nov 10:40 err-20231119104000-001216f0.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 user user  366 19 nov 10:40 combined.log
```

#### <s>And for interactive session, use `stdbuf`:</s>

Regarding [Fonic' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-standard-output-and-standard-error-to-a-file-wit/66950971#comment129994694_66950971) and after some test, I have to agree: ***with `tee`, `stdbuf` is useless.*** But ...

If you plan to use this in *interactive* shell, you must tell `tee` to not buffering his input/output:

```
# Source this to multi-log your session
[ -e lasterr.txt ] && mv -f lasterr.txt lasterr.old
[ -e lastlog.txt ] && mv -f lastlog.txt lastlog.old
exec 2> >(exec stdbuf -i0 -o0 tee -a overall.err combined.log /dev/tty >lasterr.txt)
exec 1> >(exec stdbuf -i0 -o0 tee -a overall.log combined.log /dev/tty >lastlog.txt)
```

Once **sourced** this, you could try:

```
ls -ld /tnt /tmp
```

#### More complex sample

From my [3 remarks about how to *Convert Unix timestamp to a date string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73217493/1765658)

I've used more complex command to parse and reassemble `squid`'s log in *real time*: As each line begin by an *UNIX EPOCH* with milliseconds, I split the line on 1st dot, add `@` symbol before *EPOCH SECONDS* to
pass them to `date -f -  +%F\ %T` then reassemble `date`'s output and the rest of line with a dot by using `paste -d .`.

```
exec {datesfd}<> <(:)
tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log |
    tee >(
        exec sed -u 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\..*/@\1/'|
            stdbuf -o0 date -f - +%F\ %T >&$datesfd
    ) |
        sed -u 's/^[0-9]\+\.//' |
        paste -d . /dev/fd/$datesfd -
```

With `date`, `stdbuf` was required...

#### Some explanations about `exec` and `stdbuf` commands:

- Running `forks` by using `$(...)` or `<(...)` is done by running *subshell* wich will execute *binaries* in another *subshell* (*subsubshell*). The `exec` command tell shell that there are not further command in script to be run, so *binary* (`stdbuf ... tee`) will be executed as *replacement process*, at *same level* (no need to reserve more memory for running another sub-process).

  From `bash`'s man page (`man -P'less +/^\ *exec\ ' bash`):

  > ```
  >     exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]
  >            If  command  is  specified,  it  replaces the
  >            shell.  No new process is created....
  > ```

  This is not really *needed*, but reduce system footprint.
- From `stdbuf`'s man page:

  > ```
  > NAME
  >        stdbuf  -  Run COMMAND, with modified buffering
  >        operations for its standard streams.
  > ```

  This will tell system to use unbuffered I/O for `tee` command. So all *outputs* will be *updated* immediately, when some *input* are coming.

Comment: See further: [Pipe output to two different commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108173/1765658), then follow link to *more detailled answer on this duplicate* in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107783/pipe-output-to-two-different-commands/13108173#comment47763415_13108173).

Comment: Could you explain how `exec stdbuf` helps in this context? The man page of `stdbuf` states that if does not have any effect on `tee`?

Comment: @Fonic ***Some explanations about exec and stdbuf commands***, published!

Comment: Thanks, but still: the man page of `stdbuf` states that `tee` won't be affected by it, so what's the point? Quote: `NOTE: If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams ('tee' does for example) then that will override corresponding changes by 'stdbuf'`

Comment: @Fonic Sorry for delay... I haved some tests to do... Answer edited! (Your comment is mentioned)

Answer (score 19):

Another approach:

If using older versions of Bash where `&>>` isn't available, you also can do:

```
(cmd 2>&1) >> file.txt
```

This spawns a subshell, so it's less efficient than the traditional approach of `cmd >> file.txt 2>&1`, and it consequently won't work for commands that need to modify the current shell (e.g. `cd`, `pushd`), but this approach feels more natural and understandable to me:

1. Redirect standard error to standard output.
2. Redirect the new standard output by appending to a file.

Also, the parentheses remove any ambiguity of order, especially if you want to pipe standard output and standard error to another command instead.

To avoid starting a subshell, you instead could use curly braces instead of parentheses to create a *group command*:

```
{ cmd 2>&1; } >> file.txt
```

(Note that a semicolon (or newline) is required to terminate the group command.)

Comment: This implementation causes one extra process for system to run. Using syntax `cmd >> file 2>&1` works in all shells and does not need an extra process to run.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I already explained that it spawns a subshell and is less efficient.  The point of this approach is that if efficiency isn't a big deal (and it rarely is), this way is easier to remember and harder to get wrong.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen I've updated my answer with a variant that avoids spawning a subshell.

Comment: If you truly cannot remember if the syntax is `cmd >> file 2>&1` or `cmd 2>&1 >> file` I think it would be easier to do `cmd 2>&1 | cat >> file` instead of using braces or parenthesis. For me, once you understand that the implementation of `cmd >> file 2>&1` is literally "redirect STDOUT to `file`" followed by "redirect STDERR to whatever *file* STDOUT is currently pointing to" (which is obviously `file` after the first redirect), it's immediately obvious which order you put the redirects. UNIX does not support redirecting to a stream, only to *file* descriptor pointed by a stream.

Answer (score -1):

This is terribly good!

Redirect the output to log file and stdout within the current script.

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/314678/5449346, very simple and clean, it redirects all the script's output to the log file and stdout, including the scripts called in the script:

> exec > >(tee -a "logs/logdata.log") 2>&1 prints the logs on the screen as well as writes them into a file –  shriyog  Feb 2, 2017 at
> 9:20

> Typically we would place one of these at or near the top of the script. Scripts that parse their command lines would do the redirection after parsing.
>
> Send stdout to a file
>
> exec > file with stderr
>
> exec > file
> exec 2>&1 append both stdout and stderr to file
>
> exec >> file exec 2>&1 As Jonathan Leffler mentioned in his comment:
>
> exec has two separate jobs. The first one is to replace the currently
> executing shell (script) with a new program. The other is changing the
> I/O redirections in the current shell. This is distinguished by having
> no argument to exec.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.