# Dumping dataset (.ds) file contents to a text file

Tags: unix, dataset, datastage

At work we use DataStage which uses dataset (.ds) files. I can view the contents of the file from without our UNIX environment by using:

```
orchadmin dump -name <dataset name>
```

This only dumps the contents of the file to the screen. What I would like to do is have that dump stored inside a text file which I could then open/read from within Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about DataStage, so my answer may be completely off-base, but in general in Unix to append the output of a command to a file instead of to the screen you'd use:

```
orchadmin dump -name %dataset name% >> %filename%
```

See the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239) for a little more detail.