# Create text file and fill it using bash

Tags: bash, unix

I need to create a text file (unless it already exists) and write a new line to the file all using bash.

I'm sure it's simple, but could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Have a look at [Create or append to file/s from script himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950971/1765658)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you're wanting this as a script, the following Bash script should do what you want (plus tell you when the file already exists):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e $1 ]; then
  echo "File $1 already exists!"
else
  echo >> $1
fi
```

If you don't want the "already exists" message, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e $1 ]; then
  echo >> $1
fi
```

Edit about using:

Save whichever version with a name you like, let's say "create_file" (quotes mine, you don't want them in the file name).  Then, to make the file executatble, at a command prompt do:

```
chmod u+x create_file
```

[Put the file in a directory in your path](http://www.linuxheadquarters.com/howto/basic/path.shtml), then use it with:

```
create_file NAME_OF_NEW_FILE
```

The $1 is a special shell variable which takes the first argument on the command line after the program name; i.e. $1 will pick up NAME_OF_NEW_FILE in the above usage example.

Comment: Could I replace it with "text.txt"?

Comment: @Switz:  See edit explaining $1.  If you replace $1 in the script with "text.txt", it will always use "text.txt" as the filename.

Answer (score 155):

Creating a text file in unix can be done through a text editor (vim, emacs, gedit, etc). But what you want might be something like this

```
echo "insert text here" > myfile.txt
```

That will put the text 'insert text here' into a file myfile.txt. To verify that this worked use the command 'cat'.

```
cat myfile.txt
```

If you want to append to a file use this

```
echo "append this text" >> myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you mean UNIX shell commands, just run

```
echo >> file.txt
```

`echo` prints a newline, and the `>>` tells the shell to append that newline to the file, creating if it doesn't already exist.

In order to properly answer the question, though, I'd need to know what you would want to happen if the file already does exist. If you wanted to replace its current contents with the newline, for example, you would use

```
echo > file.txt
```

**EDIT:** and in response to Justin's comment, if you want to add the newline only if the file didn't already exist, you can do

```
test -e file.txt || echo > file.txt
```

At least that works in Bash, I'm not sure if it also does in other shells.

Comment: +1. I think there's 1 other possible interpretation: create and write a newline if the file doesn't yet exist, else don't modify the file at all.

Comment: @Justin: good point, I guess I can add that one too and we'll have all the options covered.

Comment: This was by far the clearest explanation to me. Minimum commands and an accurate explanation of what they do.

Answer (score 22):

```
#!/bin/bash
file_location=/home/test/$1.json
if [ -e $policy ]; then
  echo "File $1.json already exists!"
else
  cat > $file_location <<EOF
{
      "contact": {
          "name": "xyz",
          "phonenumber":   "xxx-xxx-xxxx"
      }
    }
EOF
fi
```

This code checks if the given JSON file of the user is present in test home directory or not. If it's not present it will create it with the content. You can modify the file location and content according to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo -e "Hello there, new line!" >> new_file.txt
```

or

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/test.txt
Hello World
EOF
```

Comment: But you show two different command with two differents *effects*: The first will *append* while second will *replace content*!  Consider `-a` switch of `tee` and/or having only one `>` redirector instead of two!!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a a bit vague.  This is a shell command that does what I think you want to do:

```
echo >> name_of_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat my_file.txt | cat > new_file.txt
```

Create a ".sh" file and drop this command there, then run))

This will put the output of `my_file` to `new_file` and by the way will create it.

Instead of `cat my_file.txt` you can put any text, it automatically will be send to `new_file`.

Comment: Hem `cat | cat` is a useless fork! `cat my_file.txt >new_file.txt` will do same!!

Answer (score 0):

"Touch" command also could be used for creating a file.
Example:

```
touch new_file.txt
```

This command will create new file new_file.txt in current folder.

Comment: But `touch` won't ***fill*** the file!!

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment and sorry for the inappropriate comment...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one-liners

To execute some command if logical comparison is true:

```
[ -e myfile.txt ] && echo "myfile.txt already exists!"
```

Logical operator "AND" (&&) always executes the first command and only if exit status of that command is Success (0) then the next command is executed.

Or reversely execute command of logical comparison is false

```
[ -e myfile.txt ] || echo "insert text here" > myfile.txt
```

Logical operator "OR" (||) always executes the first command and only if exit status command is **NOT** Success (0) then the next command is executed.