# Write to file, but overwrite it if it exists

Tags: bash, unix

```
echo "text" >> 'Users/Name/Desktop/TheAccount.txt'
```

How do I make it so it creates the file if it doesn't exist, but overwrites it if it already exists. Right now this script just appends.

Answer (score 619, accepted):

The `>>` redirection operator will append lines to the end of the specified file, where-as the single greater than `>` will empty and overwrite the file.

```
echo "text" > 'Users/Name/Desktop/TheAccount.txt'
```

Comment: Some environments disallow with something like `-bash: TheAccount.txt: cannot overwrite existing file`.

Comment: See answer by @BrDaHa. Use `>|` to force overwrite existing

Comment: if your environment disallows it. It works on Ubuntu 20.10 with bash 5.

Comment: Semi-related question to this, but what's the best way to pick up all these little nuances about bash?  I never knew about this answer but it's hugely helpful.

I'm finding it hard to figure out a middle ground between "just absorb the bash reference manual cover to cover" and "googling every problem on Stackoverflow."

Comment: This answer doesn't directly answer the question. As Jake noted, @BrDaHa answer answers it.

Answer (score 161):

In Bash, if you have set noclobber a la `set -o noclobber`, then you use the syntax `>|`

For example:

```
echo "some text" >| existing_file
```

This also works if the file doesn't exist yet

---

- Check if noclobber is set with: `set -o | grep noclobber`
- For a more detailed explanation on this special type of operator, see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45203/90061)
- For a more exhaustive list of redirection operators, refer to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/90061)

Comment: @BrDaHa How can I also redirect stderr with >| as well? I tried  &>|   but it didn't work.

Comment: @TuBui not sure why it's not working for you. On my machine `&>| file` does work. What shell and version are you using?
@stimulate for zsh [both should work](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html), for bash it's [only `>|`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

Comment: @Griddo my shell is bash version 4.3.48(1)-release. `echo "aaa" &>| test.txt` results in error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token |`. My noclobber is set On.

Comment: @TuBui Apparently I wasn't testing correctly. It's not working for me either ... however the documentation doesn't state that it should be possible anyways. You probably have to stick to `echo "aaa" >| test.txt 2>&1` or use another shell.

Comment: `>!` is also working fine for me (see: http://linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/Protecting%20files%20with%20noclobber.htm)

Comment: @CyberMew because you’re using zsh

Comment: @BrDaHa ah yes you are right, it's a no go for bash.

Answer (score 40):

Despite [`NylonSmile`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4676473/547214), which is "sort of" correct.. I was unable to **overwrite** files, in this manner..

`echo "i know about Pipes, girlfriend" > thatAnswer`

> `zsh: file exists: thatAnswer`

to solve my issues.. I had to use... `>!`, *á la*..

```
[[ $FORCE_IT == 'YES' ]] && echo "$@" >! "$X" || echo "$@" > "$X"
```

Obviously, be careful with this...

Comment: This means that you have the non-default zsh option `NOCLOBBER` set. Use `setopt clobber`  to restore the default behaviour.

Answer (score 24):

If your environment doesn't allow overwriting with `>`, use pipe `|` and `tee` instead as follows:

```
echo "text" | tee 'Users/Name/Desktop/TheAccount.txt'
```

Note this will also print to the stdout. In case this is unwanted, you can redirect the output to `/dev/null` as follows:

```
echo "text" | tee 'Users/Name/Desktop/TheAccount.txt' > /dev/null
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOF > SampleFile

Put Some text here 
Put some text here
Put some text here

EOF
```

Comment: this doesn't work:

` cannot overwrite existing file`

Comment: Works in my case. Creates new file if does not exist, overwrites if file already exist.

Answer (score 4):

Just noting that if you wish to redirect both stderr and stdout to a file while you have noclobber set (i.e. `set -o noclobber`), you can use the code:

```
cmd >| file.txt 2>&1
```

More information about this can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/a/876242.

Also this answer's @TuBui's question on the answer @BrDaHa provided [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35589472/2461117) at Aug 9 '18 at 9:34.

Answer (score 2):

To overwrite one file's content to another file you use the single greater than sign, using two will append.

```
echo  "this is foo" > foobar.txt
cat foobar.txt
    > this is foo

echo "this is bar" > foobar.txt
cat foobar.txt
    > this is bar
    

echo "this is foo, again" >> foobar.txt
cat foobar.txt
    > this is bar
    > this is foo, again
```

As mentioned in other answers, if you have `noclobber` set then use the `>|` operator.

Comment: "Now to overwrite foobar..." - the `>>` is appending, not overwriting

Answer (score 0):

If the texts are output of a command, such as `ls`, you can use `cat`.

When the noclobber is set:

```
ls | cat>| TheAccount.txt
```

Otherwise, you can combine force deletion (whether the file exist or not) and `ls` command:

```
file=TheAccount.txt && rm -f $file && ls | cat > $file
```

Answer (score -4):

If you have output that can have errors, you may want to use an ampersand **and** a greater than, as follows:

`my_task &> 'Users/Name/Desktop/task_output.log'` this will redirect both stderr and stdout to the log file (instead of stdout only).

Comment: That might be true, but is unrelated to the question.