# Syntax error in docker zsh conditional command

Tags: docker, zsh

I'm trying to get a list of some deleted files in my git repo using a bash script. This however, needs to be run in a docker container and in a one liner.

I also want to only create the list of the files if there are actually any deleted files.

What I'm currently doing is:

`[[ "$(git ls-files --deleted)" =~ "filename" ]] && git ls-files --deleted >! deleted_files.txt`

Locally, this works fine. When I try in docker:

`docker exec my-container bash -c "[[ $(git ls-files --deleted) =~ "filename" ]] && git ls-files --deleted >! deleted_files.txt"`

I get this error, however:

```
bash: -c: line 0: conditional binary operator expected
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near `filename'
bash: -c: line 0: `[[  =~ filename ]] && git ls-files --deleted >! deleted_files.txt'
```

My bash knowledge is extremely lacking, so there is a great chance I'm doing something wrong, but not exactly sure what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `>!` supposed to mean?

Comment: Think this is related with me using zsh. It's NOCLOBBER flag to let me overwrite the file if it exists. Which I do want. source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676459/write-to-file-but-overwrite-it-if-it-exists#comment36200271_23585861

Comment: ok, replace `bash` with `zsh` tag then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run your command in single quotes.  When Bash sees `$variable` in double quotes it expands it *before* running the command so what you get is `=~ "filename"`.  It should be:

```
docker exec my-container bash -c '[[ $(git ls-files --deleted) =~ "filename" ]] && git ls-files --deleted >! deleted_files.txt'
```

Also make sure you `cd` to the correct directory before running `git ls-files`.

If you want to use in Makefile you have to escape each `$$` or you will get the same error as if you use double quotes. It could be:

```
docker exec gallant_stonebraker bash -c 'cd /all ; [[ $$(git ls-files --deleted) =~ "filename" ]] && git ls-files --deleted >! deleted_files.txt'
```

Comment: probably dumb question, but is there any difference if this runs via Makefile?

Comment: Yes, it would need Makefile escaping as well (`$$` instead of `$`)

Comment: @pteixeira: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)