# How to append the output to a file?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

How can I do something like `command > file` in a way that it appends to the file, instead of overwriting?

Comment: (There are lots and lots of -- perhaps far too many! -- goodies in the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) including all sorts of redirections. Adjust as needed for shell.)

Comment: You may also use tee, if you want to redirect to both STDOUT and append results to a file. For example: echo "hello" | tee -a somefile.txt, where the -a flag stands for append.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Use `>>` to append:

```
command >> file
```

Answer (score 119):

Yeah.

`cmd >> file` to redirect just *stdout* of `cmd`.

`cmd >> file 2>&1` to redirect *stdout* and *stderr* to the file (works in bash, zsh)

And if you need to use `sudo`, remember that just

`sudo cmd >> /file/requiring/sudo/privileges` does not work, as privilege elevation applies to `cmd` but not to output redirection part. However, simply using
`tee` solves the problem:

`cmd | sudo tee -a /file/requiring/sudo/privileges`

Comment: I'm using this for all output capturing program.sh 2>&1 | tee -a screen.log. "-a" stands for append.