# Using SED -n with variables in a script

Tags: macos, bash, sed, terminal, var

I am trying to use sed in a script but it keeps failing.  The commands on their own seem to work so I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

This is in Terminal in OS X (bash)

NOTE: file1.txt contains multiple lines of text

```
N=1
sed -n $Np < file1.txt > file2.txt
CONTENT=$(cat file2.txt)
echo $CONTENT
```

If I change $N to 1, it works perfectly

```
sed -n 1p <file1.txt >file2.txt
CONTENT=$(cat file2.txt)
echo $CONTENT
```

gives me

```
content of file2.txt
```

So basically, I am trying to copy the text from line 1 of a file to the start of line 2 of a file ... IF line 2 does not already start with the content of line 1.

Answer (score 3):

The shell doesn't know that you want `$N` and not `$Np`.

Do this: `${N}p`

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
sed -n $Np < file1.txt > file2.txt
```

to

```
sed -n ${N}p < file1.txt > file2.txt
```

You code has no clue what variable `Np` is...

Answer (score 0):

Since N was an integer, I ended up using the following.

```
sed -n `expr $N`p < file1 > file2
```

This also allows me to get the next line in a file using

```
sed -n `expr $N+1`p < file1 > file2
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: This does not utilise any of the advice that was provided in the answers you were given.  Using `expr $N` is overkill.  If you want to get `N+1`, you can use Bash syntax: `$((N+1))`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `>>` for append redirection. `>` overwrites the original file.

[How to append the output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342832/how-to-append-the-output-to-a-file)

Comment: Yes, it seems like it! That final sentence on the question confused me :)