# Using SED to modify the nth line of a file

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

If I want to add content to the 10th line of a file, how do I do it?

This is what I came up with:

```
sed -ie '' "10s/^/new_content/g" file.txt
```

I keep getting the message "no such file or directory"

Also, if I want to replace 10 with N+1 and the new_content with a variable $VAR, would the format still be the same?

```
VAR= $(cat fileA.txt)
sed -ie '' "`expr $N +1`s/^/$VAR/g" fileB.txt
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: `sed -ie` means that `sed` will create backup files for you by adding the extension `e` to the original file name.  Not formally wrong, but pretty implausible.  Your empty string `''` is then an empty `sed` script; this is followed by a 'file name` such as `3/^/something/g` which probably doesn't exist and then by `final.txt`.  Shell has a perfectly workable `elif` which should be used.  The semicolons after `fi` are unnecessary.  It would help no end if you include a pair of short sample inputs (the original inputs, which appear to be `length.txt` and `final.txt`, plus the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the original code so that I could stick with the original context of the thread.  I will try elif to see what happens.

Comment: `elif` is (was) stylistic, not substantive.  Instead of `else if ... then; ...; fi; fi;` you can use `elif ... then; ...; fi`  — it cuts down the number of `fi` and the amount of indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the sed -ie comment.  I was not trying to make a backup.  I was trying to call -i and -e.

Comment: On Mac, the `-i` option demands a backup suffix, which can be an empty string: `-i.bak` or `-i .bak` or `-i ''` (but not `-i''`).  Using `-i -e '…'` would give you backups with extension `-e`.  Note that GNU `sed` has different semantics for `-i`; using `-i.bak` gives you backups with `.bak` extension; `-i` on its own means backups without extensions.  If the script is to work on both Mac and GNU `sed`, you must use `-i.bak` to make the script work reliably (where the spelling of `.bak` is of your choosing, but must be present and non-empty).  (I mean it: the shell _is_ fussy about spacing).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using SED -n with variables in a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374269/using-sed-n-with-variables-in-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

Shell is fussy about spacing:

```
VAR= $(cat fileA.txt)
```

You do not want the space after the `=`.  Actually, you don't want the assignment either, unless `fileA.txt` has only one line.  You'd have to escape newlines with backslashes, etc, to get it to work, which is both hard and unnecessary.

Unless you're using an antique (non-POSIX) shell, use built-in arithmetic:

```
sed -i.bak -e "$(($N + 1))r fileA.txt" fileB.txt
```

The `$(($N + 1))` has the shell evaluate the arithmetic expression.  The `r` has `sed` read the file that is named.

> `[1addr]r file`
>    Copy the contents of file to the standard output immediately before the next attempt to read a line of input.  If file cannot be read for any reason, it is silently ignored and no error condition is set.

Comment: the space was a typo.  whoops.
fileA.txt is only 1 line.

Comment: Be careful — the shell won't know that it was a typo, and we can't do other than note what you show us; it is a common problem…

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to split `-i` and `-e`.

The final result that works was:

```
        sed -i '' -e "10s/^/CONTENT/g" file.txt
```

Or to increase Ns by +1 each time it loops:

```
        sed -i '' -e "$((N + 1))s/^/CONTENT/g" ~/dance/heatlist/prep.txt
```

I still have not figured out how to make CONTENT a variable $CONTENT

Comment: Please don't use back-ticks, and not only because they're difficult to handle in Markdown in comments.  And don't use `expr` in modern code.