# clearcase baseline_shell script

Tags: cleartool, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-automation

I am running all ClearCase commands in shell script and every command is redirecting output to a file:

```
cleartool diffbl -act -ver label1 label2 >& data.txt
cleartool diffbl -baselines label1 label2 >& data.txt
cleartool diffbl -elements label1 label2 >& data.txt
```

The issue is that all commands are running fine and generating diff log files, but it's not appending the output in same file.

Please anyone suggest how to proceed ?

I have tried with >> Also it's not working .. it's generating output in diff files.
I need single output file for all commands .

Comment: `cleartool cmd1 >> data.txt 2>&1`, followed by `cleartool cmd2 >> data.txt 2>&1` should generated the output of `cmd1` and `cm2` **in the same `data.txt` file**. If not, please mention in your question what OS you are using (Windows? Unix? what shell? Powershell, DOS? bash? csh? zsh?...)

Answer (score 0):

To append, you should use `>>` instead of `>`.

See:

- "[IO redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)" or "[Batch file redirection](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)" for Windows
- "[bash: redirect and append both stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr)"

So in your case, for a bash session (with append of stdout *and* stderr):

```
cmd >>file.txt 2>&1
```