# How to insert complicated code into a file via linux command line?

Tags: linux, append, command-line-interface

i know how to paste code into VIM editor in linux, but what i want is to skip the step when i need to open file and manually paste. Please what is the command to append, insert complicated code (containing ; ` " etc) into file (example.sh) right from linux command line?

Comment: I think you can find answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
cat example.sh <<EOF
your code here;
also with "complicated" stuff
EOF
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Mobile interface isn't that easy. ;)