# print the output in txt from command line using python

Tags: python, command-line

I want to print the output from a python.py file into a txt so i use this code:

```
python program.py > output.txt
```

that goes on the command line.

The problem is :  it only print the 90% of the outputs, it seems that the program is too long so anyway, is there a way to print all the output in the txt ? something like:

```
python program.py > output.txt 1000 lines
```

THATS THE CODE : http://pastebin.com/2bSiGKx8

THATS WHAT IT PRINTS : http://pastebin.com/r00JteMG

Comment: Your command syntax is correct. Are you sure that the python script is not just failing before it writes what you expect?

Comment: `python program.py > output.txt` should work fine.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen yes im sure in fact the compiler print everything, but when i use this command the txt only gets like 4800 lines the program have like 5000

Answer (score 1):

Within the program you can re-direct `sys.stdout` to a file object:

```
import sys
orig_sys = sys.stdout
with open('output.txt','w') as out:
    sys.stdout = out
    #your code here
    print "foo"
    print "bar"
```

or pass the file name from command line arguments:

```
#run this as: python program.py output.txt
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
orig_sys = sys.stdout
with open(filename,'w') as out:
    sys.stdout = out
    #your code here
```

But `python program.py > output.txt` is also fine, may be there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: i get some error i dont know what it is because the command line close automatically, does that work for python 2.7? =)

Comment: @CarlosWaitforitReichmannVal works fine in both py2.x and py3.x .

Comment: nice i get this error  " Value Error: I/O operation on closed file " , what can it be? i tried the first option you gave me =) thanks

Comment: @CarlosWaitforitReichmannVal your code should be inside the `with` statement, not outside of it. Because  `with` statement automatically closes the file when the `with` block is over.

Comment: thanks but when i put the code inside the with statement i and i run the program i get an infinite " RUNNING " or " LOADING " loop.. and the output.txt appear but empty

Comment: @CarlosWaitforitReichmannVal This method and `python program.py > output.txt` both are fine. There's something wrong with your code.

Comment: Sorry Ashwini my problem.  it works fine but the txt print only until some line.. maybe its a notepad length problem ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32651/discussion-between-carlos-waitforit-reichmann-val-and-ashwini-chaudhary)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem that you're running into is that program.py is printing things both to stdout (which works for going into output.txt using '>') and to stderr (which would not go into the output.txt file using '>', but would go into it if you used '2>' instead). See this question on answers to what you're trying to do: [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr)

Comment: when i use python LPIFINAL.py 2> output.txt  i get the print in the command line and the .txt is created, but it is empty

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr

Comment: i have tried the solucion to that post but i get the same only 4800 from 5000 lines. i used this command

python LPIFINAL.py >> salida.txt 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

try to flush output buffer

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

If it didn't work, instead of using print you can try logging though I guess there is not much big difference!

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('what you want to right in your file')
```

Comment: i tried it and it doesnt work.

THATS THE CODE : http://pastebin.com/2bSiGKx8

THATS WHAT IT PRINTS : http://pastebin.com/r00JteMG

Comment: @CarlosWaitforitReichmannVal try logging