# bash redirect stdout and stderr with forceful clobber

Tags: bash, stderr, overwrite, io-redirection

I have bash set to noclobber mode in my .bashrc - from the bash man page:

```
       set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]
...
              -C      If set, bash does not overwrite an existing  file  with
                      the  >,  >&, and  redirection operators.  This may be
                      overridden when creating  output  files  by  using  the
                      redirection operator >| instead of >.
```

Sometimes I want to override this behavior, so I use the `>|` redirection operator to do this.  But sometimes I want to redirect both stdout *and* stderr to a file.  The file may already exist, so I may want to clobber this file.  Given the documented operators `>&` and  `>|`, I would expect there also to be a `>|&` or `>&|` or `&>|` operator, which would redirect both stdout and stderr to the file, with a forceful overwrite.  But I am unable to find such a single operator:

```
$ ls file.txt missing
ls: missing: No such file or directory
file.txt
$ ls file.txt missing >& output.txt
bash: output.txt: cannot overwrite existing file
$ ls file.txt missing >&| output.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
$ ls file.txt missing >|& output.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
$ ls file.txt missing &>| output.txt
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
$
```

I know I can do this with a combination of `>|` and `2>&1`, but would rather be able to do this with a single operator:

```
$ ls file.txt missing >| output.txt 2>&1
$ cat output.txt 
ls: missing: No such file or directory
file.txt
$
```

Does such an operator exist, documented or otherwise?

---

I notice that there appears to be a bit of a precedence to what I am asking about - specifically in the "append" versions of these operators.  In bash 4, the `&>>` operator was introduced, which allows stdout *and* stderr to be appended to the output file.  But there appears to be no "clobber" version of this.  [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not.  You have to use the `>|`...`2>&1` solution.