# codesign output not printed to file

Tags: macos, unix, stdout, codesign

I am trying to read the output of "codesign" dynamically, but the output is only printed to the screen and not to the file:

```
    codesign -dv MyApp.app > codesign.log
```

How can I get the output of codesign?

Cheers,

Comment: Check this post to redirect both stdout and stderr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/bash-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you redirect both stdout and stderr by using the '&' character, it will send the output to the file

> *codesign -dv /Applications/Calculator.app &> codesign.log*