# eval commands with STDERR/STDOUT redirection causing problems

Tags: bash, eval, cd, tee

I'm trying to write a bash script where every command is passed through a function that evaluates the command using this line:

```
eval $1 2>&1 >>~/max.log | tee --append ~/max.log
```

An example of a case where it does not work is when trying to evaluate a cd command:

```
eval cd /usr/local/src 2>&1 >>~/max.log | tee --append ~/max.log
```

The part the causes the issue is the | tee --append ~/max.log part. Any idea why I'm experiencing issues?

Comment: What doesn't work ? It doesn't cd into the directory ?

Comment: cd doesn't work well with pipes, `cd folder | ls` for example won't put you in "folder" either

Comment: Can you move the mainfunction to a function and use `tee` for the function output? Something like `function mymain { ... }` and `mymain 2>&1 | tee -append ~/max.log` ? Or use something like `script` ?

Comment: @edi9999 It doesn't change directory when the | tee --append ~/max.log is appended

Comment: To redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e.,  in a subshell).

Therefore, `cd` **can not change the working directory of the current shell when used in a pipeline**. To work around this restriction, the usual approach would be to group `cd` with other commands and redirect the output of the group command:

```
{
    cd /usr/local/src
    command1
    command2
} | tee --append ~/max.log
```

Without breaking your existing design, you could instead handle `cd` specially in your filter function:

```
# eval all commands (will catch any cd output, but will not change directory):
eval $1 2>&1 >>~/max.log | tee --append ~/max.log
# if command starts with "cd ", execute it once more, but in the current shell:
[[ "$1" == cd\ * ]] && $1
```

Depending on your situation, this may not be enough: You may have to handle other commands that modify the environment or shell variables like `set`, `history`, `ulimit`, `read`, `pushd`, and `popd` as well. In that case it would probably be a good idea to re-think the program's design.

Comment: +1 for the cause. Also need to special-case anything that sets or declares an envvar or shell variable, if those settings are used. Including `read` etc. And `set` of `$*` and/or shell options. Or alters `ulimit` settings. Or `history`. And maybe more I've missed. Easier to redirect correctly.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks, I've made the respective statement more general to include everything that modifies environment or shell variables.