# how to save fmt.Print and log.Print into same file in Golang

Tags: shell, go

In shell, I use `go run file > output`, but only fmt.Print are saved into output. All the log.Print still output to the screen! And after I searched on the Internet, I found I can set ouput directory for log, but how can I save both log and fmt in the same file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logger writes to STDERR while fmt.PrintXXX functions write to STDOUT.

You have two choices:

1) Capture STDERR to the file.
Bash like shells use:

```
go run file > output 2>&1
```

2) Set the logger's [Output](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#SetOutput) to [os.Stdout](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables)

Then you run like normal `go run file > output` and both the logger and fmt go to the same place.

```
log.SetOutput(os.StdOut)
```