# Node.js full console redirect into a file

Tags: node.js, console, redirectstandardoutput

When we want a Node.js application to redirect every `console.log` and `console.info` into a file, we can use either `>fileName` or `1>fileName`, which hooks into `process.stdout`.

And when we want a Node.js application to redirect every `console.warn` and `console.error` into a file, we can use `2>fileName`, which hooks into `process.stderr`.

But how can we redirect the complete console output (for all console methods) into a single file?

I'm looking for something that works on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following syntax works: `> filename 2>&1`

Per this thread: [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

Comment: I don't know about Linux yet, but at least on Windows it doesn't work, producing error `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`.

Comment: Ah, I skimmed too quicky and missed the "Windows" part. :-)

Comment: I have updated your answer to the one that answers it precisely ;)

Comment: Hmm...the syntax looks pretty much identical:
https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true