# Append output from both stdout and stderr of every command of a bash script to file

Tags: bash, macos, redirect, stdout, stderr

Here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/876267/1579327

I learned how to do that for a single command `cmd` appending output to `file.txt`

```
cmd >>file.txt 2>&1
```

But my script contains many statements and commands.

And I would like to avoid appending `>>file.txt 2>&1` to every line.

Is there a directive to let me to do that by default for every subsequent command?

---

Side note: I'm looking for a solution suitable also for MacOs X's bash

Comment: you could use heredocs or subshells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of your script you can use `exec` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# append stdout/stderr to a file
exec >> file.log 2>&1

# script starts here
```