# Sails/Node: Logging severe/crashing errors to file

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm running Sails.js v0.11.0 in NodeJS 5.12.0.

I sometimes run into a severe error, which causes my whole node js to crash. For example this code in a Sails controller

```
module.exports = {

  fooFunction: function () {
    console.log("Starting to do a silly thing");
    postgresClient.connectClient(function(err, client) {
      client.query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = $1", [req.user], function(err, result) {
      });
    });
  },
}
```

results in

```
client.query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = $1", [req.user], function(err, result) {
                                                            ^
ReferenceError: req is not defined
```

I'm also wondering why this error - unlike many others - is not caught somehow and does not result in something like

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

while the app keeps running.

But that's not my point.

My point is: How can I log this severe error message which causes my app to crash into a file?

It's not included in my standard sails.log file, where all "normal" Sails errors go in. Nor does it get logged if I change the standard output to a file running my app with the command `node app.js > myfile.log`. In this case, the content of `myfile.log` is just

```
[32minfo[39m:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
[32minfo[39m:    v0.11.0             |\
[...]
Starting to do a silly thing
```

and then it stops. The actual error is not there. It's just on my console. And this is very annoying when trying to debug a remote app running on a headless system. So, how can I get those errors into a log file?

Comment: You can capture `stderr` output into same file by `node app.js >myfile.log 2>&1`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash