# how to redirect `command ...` all output into a file in linux?

Tags: shell

I'm running `command xxx xxx` in linux, and I want to redirect all output, including std/warn/err output into one file IN ORDER.

How to deal with this?

For example, if I run `command xxx xxx 2>file`, the file will only contains error message. If I run `command xxx xxx 1>file`, the file will only contains std message. But I want all message together, not devided message. How to deal with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
command >outfile 2>&1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this simpler way

```
$ command arg1 arg2 >& command.out
```

This is typical C shell way but works well on most advanced shells such as bash.