# log ALL output of console

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, logging

I am trying to log something in the console, but it doesn't work. The output is:

```
Resolving...
+ /keyboard
+ /keyboard/windows.keylayout
+ /keyboard/hardware.txt
Addition count 3 src: 60.42KB
 61868 / 61868 [====================================================] 100.00% 0s
```

I want that into a .log file.

But it only takes "Resolving...", when I execute `"script >> script.log"` as the **first** line, I guess that's because of the "+", how can I fix that, that it will log ALL of the output into that file?

```
cd /home/andre/test/ && /usr/local/bin/drive_armv7 pull -no-prompt keyboard 2>&1 >> error.log
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is all this output going into stdout? Or is some stuff getting written to stderr?

Comment: I don't actually know, how do I find that out?

Comment: It's possible that some of that output is going to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.  `>>` by itself only redirects `stdout`.  Possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

Comment: I tired 2>&1 and it isn't working either...

Comment: Have tried the variations described here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Comment: yes I did, doesn't help either. Is is possible that it is buffered, because those messages in the console are displayed a bit delayed, so maybe >> only takes the immediate messages?

Comment: What exactly is the script doing?

Comment: it is a google drive script that fetches data and downloads it. The files that are downloaded are displayed in the shell.

Comment: If the script explicitly writes to your `tty` there is no simple way to redirect that. You can run it under a pseudo-tty with something like Expect, maybe google for that.

Answer (score 1):

Order of assignment?

```
cd /home/andre/test/ && /usr/local/bin/drive_armv7 pull -no-prompt keyboard 2>&1 >> error.log
```

tells stderr to go where stdout is going, which is the terminal. THEN you tell stdout to go into the log. Switch them -

```
cd /home/andre/test/ &&
/usr/local/bin/drive_armv7 pull -no-prompt keyboard >> error.log 2>&1
```

That tells stdout to go into the log, THEN tells stderr to go where stdout is going...which is now the log.

Comment: andre@raspberrypi:~/test $ cat error.log 
Resolving...
andre@raspberrypi:~/test $

The same problem, that wasn't the issue...

Comment: Need to see the actual execution. I assume you're using `set -x` somewhere in a loop to get those leading plus signs? Could we see some of the code, or at least something structurally identical?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are running a default program called script

```
user@apollo:~$ script test
Script started, file is test

user@apollo:~$ which script
/usr/bin/script
```

If "script" is a local executable called "script.sh", you should run it as following

```
./script.sh
```

Trying to reproduce your issue gives no unexpected output

```
cat > script.sh <<EOF
echo "Resolving..."
echo "+ /keyboard"
echo "+ /keyboard/windows.keylayout"
echo "+ /keyboard/hardware.txt"
echo "Addition count 3 src: 60.42KB"
echo "61868 / 61868 [====================================================] 100.00% 0s"
EOF
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh >> script.log
cat script.log
```

The unexpected behaviour depends on what your script is trying to do

Comment: is it possible that the script somehow does EOF in it so it stops writing into into the log file? If yes is there anything I can do to just ignore that and simply track the output of the terminal?

Comment: Also when I use a cronjob for that, it also just tells me "Resolving..." in the mail, I get as a result... What could that problem be?

Comment: EOF was just a Bash Here document example. If you edit your original question with the content of your script its much easier to help you debug :)