# Does &>> not work in Bash on Mac OS?

Tags: bash, macos, redirect

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash), the shortcut

```
cmd &>> outfile
```

can be used. And to use this with Mac OS, I would need to upgrade to bash 4. I have done that using homebrew but this shortcut doesn't seem to work and

```
cmd >> outfile 2>&1
```

works.

Is there a reason that `&>>` doesn't work on Mac OS?

Comment: Just to check, you're sure you are actually running the Homebrew-installed version of Bash? (One way to be absolutely sure is to make a short script that prints out the Bash version and then runs a command that tests `&>>`, then run that script.)

Comment: When I type `bash --version`, it says GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0), so I think I am running on version 4.