# Cannot redirect output of program to file

Tags: bash

I have modified an open-source program called mosquitto that I run using the command `./mosquitto -c ../mosquitto.conf -v`. The mosquitto program will run indefinitely until you quit it using ctrl+c.

As part of my testing, I want to create a bash script that runs the program and saves all of the logs (which are printed to the screen) to a text file, which it will then parse to determine some statistics. I am redirecting the output to a file as stated on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash) stackoverflow post, but nothing is being saved (the logs are still print to the terminal). Does anyone know what the issue might be? Is there some other method I could use?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ../ && make && cd src
./mosquitto -c ../mosquitto.conf -v >> logs.txt
```

Comment: What happens if you use `./mosquitto -c ../mosquitto.conf -v 2> logs.txt` instead?

Comment: or `&>>` to redirect both stdout and stderr.

Comment: You can send the output of your `bash` script to a log file which will help you avoid printing it on the terminal. Also, a search in google says that logs are configured in the `mosquitto.conf` file [Check This](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-logging/)

Comment: That's exactly what the last line `./mosquitto -c ../mosquitto.conf -v >> logs.txt` is attempting to do. I'm saying that the normal method that otherstackoverflow says would work is not working.

Comment: Thanks about the mosquitto.conf tip, I didn't realise I could set it in the config.

Comment: @annedroiid, no I meant the output of the `bash` script, not the output of the `mosquitto` command. Let us know if setting `logs` in the `conf` fixes your issue.

Comment: As I stated above, the reason I wanted to output the logs into a file was so that later in the same script it could do some analysis on them. So just outputting the results of the bash script wouldn't work, unless I wanted to be silly and have two bash scripts (one to run the program, then one to run the one that runs the program).

Answer (score -1):

I have to presume that the reason why it won't redirect the output is due to the way Mosquitto is written, particularly since as mathB pointed out there is a flag in the configuration file which can set the output of the logs to a file.