# mysqldump prints empty file on execution

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using the following code to try and execute a `mysqldump` to save my tables and information.
Of course my username and password are included from my database class and they work fine.

```
$string = 'mysqldump -u'.$db->user.' -p'.$db->pass.' '.$db->db.' > /home/user/public_html/'.$filename;
$result=exec($string,$output);
if($output==''){ echo "Error"; }
else { echo "GOOD"; }
```

The script echo's the "GOOD" remark however the log file is empty.  However if I run the string:

```
'mysqldump --help > /home/user/public_html/'.$filename;
```

It will print the help information to the file.  So I have to ask, why isn't it working otherwise?  Am I missing something as it did seem pretty straight forward.

Comment: Have you tried turning on error reporting to see if you get any errors running the above?

Comment: Try to run the command inside your shell. Maybe it writes to stderr without returning an error. You could also try to send stderr to the file as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash). You might get at least some output.

Comment: @Cyclonecode Yes, I have done the following so far:
 `$string = '/usr/bin/mysqldump --password=\''.$db->pass.'\' --user='.$db->user.' '.$db->db.'  --single-transaction >/home/dnidesig/public_html/'.$filename.'  2>&1';` and have gotten the error that `Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'dnidesig_dniroot'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect`

Comment: However, my password and username work with my php code and have "All Privileges" otherwise.