# I successfully used the curl code to download text into visual studio code. Is there a way to redirect this and save it as a text file?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

After using the code curl -http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1041/1041.txt
the text appeared in terminal. How do I transfer that text to a txt file in a subfolder?

I've tried using echo, but I can figure out how to get the whole text. I'm new to programming, so this is the only thing I know how to do so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)

Answer (score 0):

You should try going to the subfolder where you want the file stored and then run -curl http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1041/1041.txt > output_filename.out

The > symbol directs the output to wherever the filename after the > symbol is.