# how to saved all the old value that is displayed in the terminal

Tags: python

I have a python script that contains a function update and it displays the results in the terminal but the old value has been cleared. I want to keep all the values thank you

Comment: Hi, Add your code here, Will check and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

For your python script `foo.py`, run it as

```
python foo.py > output.txt
```

this will save the output of `foo.py` in the file `output.txt`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash) thread.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, `>` will create a new output file everytime, overwriting any previous file with the same name. If you wish to append the output, use `>>`.

Comment: Single `>` will cause the file to being rewritten each time the output is redirected. `>>` ensures that the output is appended.