# Redirect to a file STDOUT first and then STDERR

Tags: bash, redirect, awk, stdout, stderr

I have a gawk code like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

1 {
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        print $0
        print $0, i > "/dev/stderr"
    }
}
```

I want to redirect to a file tmp, first the stdout and then the stderr. I tried this:

```sh
gawk -f Documents/gawk_script.awk ./file &> tmp
```

But this call append to the file first stderr. I don't want to divide them into two files, so I'm asking if there's a way to do that.

In ./file there's such a line:

```
hello
hello
howareyou
well
well
```

while in tmp file

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
howareyou
howareyou
howareyou
howareyou
howareyou
well
well
well
well
well
well
well
well
well
well
well
hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
hello 4 
hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3
hello 4
howareyou 0
howareyou 1
howareyou 2
howareyou 3
howareyou 4
well 0
well 1
well 2
well 3
well 4
well 0
well 1
well 2
well 3
well 4
```

Comment: You mention in your question that the file `tmp` contains first `stderr` while in your output the file seems to have first `stdout`. Could you please elaborate what you mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no good way* to tell awk or the shell that it must buffer stderr until the tool finishes executing. Keep it simple and just do this:

```
awk -f script.awk file > out 2>tmp; cat tmp >> out && rm -f tmp
```

Otherwise you could buffer stderr yourself and print at the end (but this will only work for stderr messages you are manually printing, not messages gawk is generating itself):

```
{
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        print $0
        errs = errs $0 OFS i ORS
    }
}
END {
    printf "%s", errs > "/dev/stderr"
}
```

and then call as:

```
awk -f script.awk file > out 2>&1
```

Of course you don't actually need to use stderr at all if that's all you're doing with it, just print to stdout.

*There may be some arcane incantation you can use to make this happen if the planets align a certain way and/or you have certain tools or a certain shell but just keep it simple as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are encountering is due to the buffering of the streams `stdout` and `stderr`. Both streams have different default buffer-settings. While `stdout` is line-buffered when writing to a terminal, it is very well buffered when it writes to a stream/pipe/file. The stream `stderr` on the other hand is **always** unbuffered. That is why you first encounter the output of `stderr` and only later the output of `stdout` in your file `tmp`. Be aware, however, that the output will be interleaved when you output more lines as all of a sudden the buffer of `stdout` will be full and written to the file, following again with some output of `stderr` until the next buffer of `stdout` is full. The problem is nicely explained in the following page:

- http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

One of the ugly hacks you can apply is the usage of `stdbuf` to change the buffering of the datastreams of `awk`:

```
$ stdbuf -oL -eL awk '{...}' file.txt &> tmp.txt
```

Here we use `stdbuf` to set buffering mode of the streams `stdout` and `stderr` to line-buffering and thus the output of your code would look like:

```
hello
hello 1
hello
hello 2
...
```

If you really want first **all** output of `stdout` followed by all output of `stderr`, you should follow the approach mentioned by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56407419/8344060).

Comment: As an alternative to using `stdbuf`, a call to `fflush()` at the end of every pair of prints within awk can force all of the output to be interleaved as it occurs too. Note that if you're using `print | "cat>&2"` (portable to all awks) to print to stderr instead of `print > "/dev/stderr"` (only works in some awks) then you'll also need to `close("cat>&2")` after every print to avoid `cat` also doing buffering.

Answer (score 1):

### This is a small example:

*I am not sure what you mean, if I understand it...*

If you want to redirect `stdout` to `file_out` , redirect `stderr` to `file_err` , you can do this...

```
command > file_out 2> file_err
```

Comment: sorry if you don't understand, I'll explain better. Yes, I want to redirect both of them to a file, but the stdout must be redirected before stderr. So in the output file, I will have first the words without number and then those with number.

Comment: - So, this is not possible in one step, you need to add some logic to control the text. Suppose your filename is `tmp`.
    
    1. You should create a temporary file.

    2. Then redirect stderr to this temporary file

    3. After the command is finished, copy and append the stderr in this temporary file to your `tmp` file.

    4. Delete this temporary file

- If you want to use it multiple times, you need to add another step (add a step between 1-2 above): **cut the number-terminated lines that in `tmp` into the temporary file.**

Comment: Okay, So I need to create two files to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Lit bit old, but if someone still needs it:

```
echo "some stuff" | awk '{
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        print $0;
        # print i on stderr
        system(">&2 echo " i);
    }
}'
```