# Console warnings to file

Tags: python

I am running a python script using `pandas.read_csv` to import a csv file. Pandas provides console warnings when it doesn't see what it expects such as:

```
Skipping line 163: Expected 41 fields in line 163, saw 42
```

How can I log this to a text file?

If I run the script from a command line, `python > logfile.txt` only the output of print shows up in the file, not the warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `stderr`

In bash, there are 3 default streams:

STDOUT: Redirected by `>` or `1>`, this is standard output from a program.

STDERR: Redirected by `2>`, this is diagnostic output from a program.

STDIN: Input from console, use `<` to input it.

```
./prog 2> errorlog.txt >logfile.txt
```

If you want to redirect ALL output to STDOUT, use:

```
./prog 2>&1
```

Here is some more information:
[I/O Redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

This line worked for me

```sh
python script.py >>script.out 2>&1
```

which appends STDOUT (1) to `script.out` file and redirects STDERR (2) to the same file (&1)

Note that output is appended, so you may want to call `> script.out` to reset the file beforehand, as in

```sh
> script.out; python script.py >> script.out 2>&1
```

Sources

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/876242/8462678
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57272607/8462678 (accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.stderr=openfile("file.txt",'w')
df=pandas.read_csv(filepath,on_bad_lines='warn')
sys.stderr.close()
```

This code will store all the warnings that will be generated by pandas.read_csv

Comment: `openfile` is not a builtin function.