# How to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file from within a bash script?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I want to add a command to my bash script that directs all stderr and stdout to specific files. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash) and many other sources, I know that from the command line I would use:

```
/path/to/script.sh >> log_file 2>> err_file
```

However, I want something inside my script, something akin to these slurm flags:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o slurm.stdout.txt # Standard output log
#SBATCH -e slurm.stderr.txt # Standard error log

<code>
```

Is there a way to direct output from within a script, or do I need to use `>> log_file 2>> err_file` every time I call the script? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this at the start of your bash script:

```
# Redirected Output
exec > log_file 2> err_file
```

If the file does exist it is truncated to zero size. If you prefer to append, use this:

```
# Appending Redirected Output
exec >> log_file 2>> err_file
```

If you want to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same file, then you can use:

```
# Redirected Output
exec &> log_file
# This is semantically equivalent to
exec > log_file 2>&1
```

If you prefer to append, use this:

```
# Appending Redirected Output
exec >> log_file 2>&1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
exec >> file
exec 2>&1
```

at the start of your bash script. This will append both stdout and stderr to your file.

Answer (score 3):

```
#SBATCH --output=serial_test_%j.log   # Standard output and error log
```

This will send all output, i.e stdout *and* stderr to a single log file called `serial_test_<JOBID>.log`

Ref: https://help.rc.ufl.edu/doc/Sample_SLURM_Scripts