# Cannot set content of locust.stats_logger into log file

Tags: python-3.x, logging, locust

In locust Docs, https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/logging.html.

locust.stats_logger is used to periodically print the current stats to the console. The stats does not go into the log file when --logfile is used by default.So I set --logfile args in console.

`locust -f mylocust.py --headless -t 10s -L=DEBUG --logfile=output.txt`

But in output.txt,I only get the locust log.How can I get the output of locust.stats_logger in logfile?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would just be to direct the output of the command to the same file. That's what I do. Check this out: [How to redirect and append both stdout and stderr to a file with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash)