# Why does "ls not_existing_file 2&>1 > log.txt" not write anything to log.txt?

Tags: bash, zsh

I want to redirect stout and stderr of `ls` to `log.txt`. Why does this command

```
ls not_existing_file 2>&1 > log.txt
```

result in an empty log.txt file?

Comment: Because the order of your redirections is wrong: `ls not_existing_file > log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Also `2&>1 != 2>&1` ?

Comment: @Jetchisel That was a typo in the questions, I fixed it.

Comment: @zwithouta, ok I thought that was a thing in `zsh` :-)

Comment: _I want to redirect the stderr of `ls` to `log.txt`_ In that case `ls not_existing_file 2>log.txt` should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to you trying to redirect the output of the redirect merge operator stdout into the log file rather than the output of the command itself.

What you could do instead is redirect the stdout of the command into the log file, and then append the redirect merge operator as follows:
`ls not_existing_file > log.txt 2>&1`

This question has also been answered in [How to redirect and append both standard output and standard error to a file with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-standard-output-and-standard-error-to-a-file-wit)