# Cannot redirect stderr to file in bash when using VMAF cmd

Tags: bash, console, vmaf

After executing [VMAF](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/blob/master/libvmaf/tools/README.md) command

```
vmaf -r "r.Y4M" -d "d.Y4M" --threads=24
```

the result is outputted to the console

```
VMAF version 2.3.0
901 frames ÔíéÔáÇ 41.36 FPS←[K
vmaf_v0.6.1: 94.171817
```

I'd like it to be outputted to a file instead.  I thought that redirecting stdout/stderr to txt file would be sufficient

```
vmaf -r "r.Y4M" -d "d.Y4M" --threads=24 &> result.txt
```

The `result.txt` file is created but it remains empty after executing the command.

I tried the same method for `ffmpeg` command

```
ffmpeg -i "in.mov" -c:v libx264 "out.mp4" &> result.txt
```

and it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try the canonical way of redirecting in Bash: [How to redirect and append both standard output and standard error to a file with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-standard-output-and-standard-error-to-a-file-wit)

Comment: Tried `>> result.txt`, `&>> result.txt`, `>>result.txt 2>&1` but nothing works :/ It feels like it just stops outputting anything to stderr as soon as I redirect it.

Comment: `It feels like it just stops outputting anything to stderr as soon as I redirect it.` That could be the case. Try `-o result.txt`. Or one of the other options for output format.