# Suppress console logging on Linux

Tags: bash, shell

I am working with shell scripts for some automation tasks. I have functions defined in my script which are executed however the tasks performed by some of the functions logs a lot of data on the terminal screen which is irrelevant.

Is there a way in which I can suppress the console logging before calling a particular function and enable it back  when the function execution is finished?

Comment: Write the functions to stdout, stderr or tty?

Comment: could you elaborate please.

Comment: typically there are a few output streams for a program (no necessarily a shell script), named respectively standard output (`stdout`), standard error (`stderr`). Sometimes a standard log (`stdlog`) is added to the list, and a program, can access terminal device directly via `tty`. The functions write their output to one of those streams.

You may check examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-standard-output-and-standard-error-to-a-file-wit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supress the output of a program *redirecting* it to the special file `/dev/null`.

Note that there are two kind of output, normal output (`stdout`) and error output (`stderr`)

To redirect all output use

```
command_or_function [args] &>/dev/null
```

If you want to supress the output for multiple commands, use `{ }`

```
{
  ...
  commands
  ...
} &>/dev/null
```

The redirection can be placed at any position, even before command.

```
&>/dev/null echo hello
```

To redirect only `stdout` use `>`

To redirect only `stderr` use `2>`

[See more here](https://devhints.io/bash)