# Output result of a cpp file to a text file

Tags: c++, linux, unix, g++

In a unix/Linux environment, I'm trying to output the execution results of the cpp file to a text file instead of the console.

So I've already compiled my cpp file as follows:

1. g++ main.cpp -o main
2. ./main

I remember someone saying that I would the the > sign to output it to a text file , but would appreciate it if someone can help.

Tried outputting  g++ main.cpp > test.txt but didn't work

Comment: After doing `g++ main.cpp -o main`, try `./main > test.txt` instead of `./main`. Doing `g++ main.cpp > test.txt` will not work, because that will only write the compiler output  (which should be nothing) to `test.txt`. You instead want to write your program's output to `test.txt`.

Comment: `./main >test.txt 2>&1` if there is error output too. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-to-redirect-and-append-both-standard-output-and-standard-error-to-a-file-wit)

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you should distinguish between *compiling* and *running*.

> So I've already compiled my cpp file as follows:
>
> 1. g++ main.cpp -o main
> 2. ./main

The first step is compiling the *source file* `main.cpp` into an *executable file* named `main`. The second step is not doing the compilation job, it's actually running the executable `main`.

Then, to output the running result of a command to a file, you'll do `[command] >[filename]` (e.g. `./main >test.txt`). Essentially this associates the named file with the *standard output* of the program.

`g++ main.cpp > test.txt` will write the standard output of running `g++` to `test.txt`, thus you get nothing. Instead you should do `./main >test.txt`.

Programs often output error messages to *standard error* stream, in order to capture these too, you can do `./main >test.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: Use `./main > test.txt 2>&1` to capture both stdout and stderr.