# Adding a prefix to all output lines of "apt-update && apt-upgrade in BASH?

Tags: bash, scripting, stdout, stderr, prefix

I'm trying to add a prefix to all output of the following command:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade`

I've been scouring the internet and it seem there are 2 outputs to handle. STDOUT, and STDERR.

I've found the following:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade > >(sed "s/^/[prefix1]/") 2> >(sed "s/^/[prefix2]/" >&2)`

Which seems to redirect stdout and stderr and append the [prefix1] and [prefix2], however, there are still some output lines which do not have a prefix, and I'm wondering what I'm missing?

The output looks like this:

```bash
Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease     
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease   
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease      
Hit:5 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt mantic-pgdg InRelease   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
[prefix2]
[prefix2]WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
[prefix2]
[prefix1]Reading package lists...
[prefix1]Building dependency tree...
[prefix1]Reading state information...
[prefix1]Calculating upgrade...
[prefix1]0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I prefix the lines which start with `HIT:`, `Reading`, `Building`?

Comment: Enclose both commands in parenthesis or braces : `{ sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade ;} > >(sed "s/^/[prefix1]/") 2> >(sed "s/^/[prefix2]/" >&2)`

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950971/1765658)

Comment: You may enclose commands without parenthesis, by using any other kind of grouping (`if...then...else`,`case... esac`,`for...;do done`: try this: `if :;then ls -ld /t{mp,nt};ls -ld /t{mp,nt};fi 2> >(sed 's/^/E:/') > >(sed 's/^/S:/')`

Comment: This does work, and does solve my issue, but, I'm having some issues running other commands. I'm trying to run a `git clone`, but when I do, I simply get no output at all.

`{git clone https://github.com/repo $SITE_DIR} 2> >(sed 's/^/E:/') > >(sed 's/^/S:/')` Otherwise, this works. Is there something different about the output of `git clone`?

Comment: You need a semi-colon before closing brace: `{ ... ;} `! But for only one command, this is useless.