# Is there a C/C++ equivalent for Python's "__init__.py"?

Tags: python, c++, c++11

In Python when you create a module you create an `__init__.py` file (at least, usually). Is there a C/C++ equivalent of this thing? I mean is there a way to `#include` a directory actually including a file inside it?

Comment: There is absolutely no logic behind the preprocessors handling of `#include`. It is really just a copy/past, that's it.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i know how to include a file that is in a directory, you just have to specify the path. What i wanna know is how to automate the process

Comment: Similarly, [How to include all source files from a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750831/how-to-include-all-source-files-from-a-folder)

Comment: Have a look at CMake, it is a quite common way to manage the project.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i have already done this thing. My project has a file in it where the whole code of the library is included. However i want to include that file (from an extern one) just by doing `#include "project"` (or something similar) and not `#include "project/init.h"`

Comment: There is no such thing in C++11: You can have project management helping (e.g. Cmake), you can load/unload dynamic libraries runtime to add/remove "modules". Beside this, you have the #include which basically is a dummy copy/paste. Since C++20 you have "Modules" but they don't work as Python ones.

Comment: In C/C++ you really wat to include the **necesary** for each file, I think it's a better practice to have several (but really necesary) `#include` lines than a general (that may unclude unnecessary files)  one

Comment: Starting with C++20 you can create your own modules in C++. For C++11 there's no such feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in C++ itself. Nor it seems the typically used compilers support it. A feature similar to Python's modules is introduced in C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules

You may want to look at build systems like [SCons](https://scons.org/) or [CMake](https://cmake.org/) which will allow you to implement some preprocessing before the actual C++ preprocessing/compilation. For example, you can use them to generate a header file including all the headers from a directory, or do anything more complicated if you really need it.

Please do take into consideration the last part of the last sentence: do you really need it? Usually code is much easier to maintain if all its dependencies are explicit. Having a header including "everything" will make it hard to track. One can imagine some valid reasons for breaking this rule of course, e.g. if these headers are generated as well and it's desirable to have an automated way of including all of them. Still, it's best if scope of such "magic" is self-contained and as small as possible.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. What is the method used by, let's say, `#include <any>`? That adds several functions to `std`.

Comment: @Giuppox These functions are either defined in this single include file (`any.h`) or in headers transitively included by `any.h`.

Comment: @Giuppox it looks through the system include paths (not recursively) for a file named `any`, and then copy-pastes the content of the first one it finds. On my system it's `/usr/include/c++/7/any`

Comment: Standard hearders don't have an extention, so `#include <any>` looks for a file named `any`, not `any.h` or `any.hpp`.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a C/C++ equivalent of this thing?

Not equivalent, but for header-only libraries, it is common practise to include an aggregate header, which is a header than includes other header files. For example, if we look at [boost filesystem](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/tree/develop/include/boost):

```
/mnt/e/Repository/filesystem/include/boost/
├── filesystem
│   ├── config.hpp
│   ├── convenience.hpp
│   ├── detail/
│   ├── directory.hpp
│   ├── exception.hpp
│   ├── file_status.hpp
│   ├── fstream.hpp
│   ├── operations.hpp
│   ├── path.hpp
│   ├── path_traits.hpp
│   └── string_file.hpp
└── filesystem.hpp **Aggregate header**
```

Contents of *filesystem.hpp*:

```
...
#  include <boost/filesystem/config.hpp>
#  include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#  include <boost/filesystem/exception.hpp>
#  include <boost/filesystem/directory.hpp>
#  include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#  include <boost/filesystem/file_status.hpp>
#  include <boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp>
#  include <boost/filesystem/string_file.hpp>

...
```

Note that **this does not behave the same as** the `__init__.py` file, it is a convenience feature. You need only include the aggregate header, to access all of the functionality.

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't behave the same, but this is probably the closest thing to defining an `__all__` array in `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yep, I do try to highlight that fact. Also, you have to write the header manually, which is probably the pain-point from a python-dev's perspective.