# include directory in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to include a hole directory that contain C header classes in C ? I generated C classes from ASN.1 description , shall I include every header or is it possible to include the hole directory where the classes are generated ?

Comment: You cannot `#include` a directory (or wildcards).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061582/c-include-all-files-in-a-directory