# How to add header files path relative to the current file?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio-2013, eigen, mex

I have the file `mx_minimum_power.cpp` in the following directory

```
D:\thesis library.Data\ALOS-PALSAR 12x2\San Francisco L 12x2
```

and 14 header files that I want to include to the cpp file in the following directory:

```
D:\thesis library.Data\ALOS-PALSAR 12x2\San Francisco L 12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues
```

so the relative path to these `.h` files with respect to my `.cpp` file is `\Eigen\Eigenvalues`
How should I include all those header files relative path.
I've done so far:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "\Eigen\Eigenvalues"

using std::complex;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace Eigen;

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *arraysizePtr = NULL;
    arraysizePtr = mxGetPr(prhs[9]);
    const int arraysize = (int)*arraysizePtr;
    const int matrixDimention = 3;
}
```

but when I run the following command in matlab in order to build the `.mexw64` file:

```
mex -g mx_minimum_power.cpp
```

I get the error:

```
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional'.  
Error using mex
mx_minimum_power.cpp
D:\thesis library.Data\ALOS-PALSAR 12x2\San Francisco L 12x2\mx_minimum_power.cpp(6) : fatal
error C1083: Cannot open include file: '\Eigen\Eigenvalues': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your should either include all your header files manually, e.g. `#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\header.h"` or consider techniques from this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061582/include-all-files-in-a-directory

Comment: I may be in the minority, but I consider paths in `#include` directives a bad idea. If I have time I'll try to find some of the questions from people trying to work around such things in legacy code.

Comment: `#include "\Eigen\Eigenvalues"` means look for the file `Eigenvalues` in a folder named `Eigen` that is in the root of whatever drive the code is in. In this case it is looking for the file `D:\Eigen\Eigenvalues`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "Eigen/Eigenvalues/first.of.14.h"
...
```

Then let the compiler know to look in "." as a base path for includes, assuming you run the compiler from the source directory.  In gcc/g++ one uses "-I.".  I couldn't find the equivalent on MSDN, but there is one.  I used it years ago.

That literally answers your question, but I would tell the compiler to look in "Eigen\Eigenvalues" and then just use the 14 names as above without the two levels of directories.