# Redirecting stdout and stderr to variable within bash script

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I've written a 'generic' bash script (= generic_script.sh) which serves as a wrapper to start an actual bash script (= actual_script.sh), depending on the parameters given. The stdout of both the generic_script as well as the actual_script should be written to a specific file/folder. The same goes for the stderr of the generic_script as well as the actual_script.

The write path of those two files (stdout and stderr) is dependent on the arguments, which get parsed in the script. Here's a simplified call:

```
# wrapper-script     job-id job-script                args
./generic_wrapper.sh JOB001 /path/to/actual_script.sh arg1 arg2
```

generic_wrapper.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    # Guarding clauses
    ...

    # Parsing arguments
    stdout_file="/some/path/$1/timestamp.stdout"         # Creating job-id specific folders
    stderr_file="/some/path/$1/timestamp.stderr"

    # Sourcing actual_script.sh
    source "${path}/$2" 1>"${stdout_file} 2>"${stderr_file}"

    # Statistics
    ...

} > "${stdout_file}" 2>"{$stderr_file}" # throws error
echo "${stdout_file}" # returns correct file path
```

actual_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Just an example."
```

However, executing this code returns `/wrappers/generic_at_wrapper.sh: line 108: : No such file or directory` error. This strongly implies, that at the time of redirection, the variable `stdout_file` has not been filled. I reckon that this is tied to the order, in which the variables are resolved or the bash is interpreted.

If I `echo` the value of said variable `stdout_file`(as well as `stderr_file`) on the next line, I get the correct value whatsoever, meaning that this is tied to the `{} >` construct. The redirection method is from this [SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314675/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-entire-shell-script-within-the-script-itself).

How can I redirect the stdout and stderr to a file path stored in a variable? The file path variable itself gets calculated in the `{}` construct and doesn't seem available right after closing the brackets.

Comment: Are you missing a closing quote here `} > "${stdout_file}`?

Comment: @Cole Tierney: you're absolutely right. But this was solely an issue in my pseudo code above. Fixed it.

Comment: @Lino: You are **using** `stdout_file` outside the `{...}` sequence, but define it inside. When bash sets up the outside redirection, the variables are still undefined. Your redirection is expanded to `> ""`, and this is what the error message says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect for the entirety of your code, instead of using blocks, use the `exec` command. That is:

```
stdout_file="/some/path/$1/timestamp.stdout"         # Creating job-id specific folders
stderr_file="/some/path/$1/timestamp.stderr"
exec >"$stdout_file" 2>"$stderr_file"

# ...all code below this point has stdout going to stdout_file, and stderr to stderr_file
```

Comment: I'd prefer this method of redirection, as it immediately shows, that a redirection takes place without having to read the entire script/block. I've removed the block `{}`, created the stdout and stderr variables before doing the `exec` and the timestamp specific files get created. Surprisingly, there is no output (to either stdout or stderr) before I have sourced the `actual_script.sh`. So doing an `echo "test"` immediately after the exec will not be visible in the output. According to the example given, the first line written is `Just an example.` Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'd need to see a reproducer. With some commands you might see libc's buffering behaviors causing writes to be deferred (until there's enough content to be able to do a larger, lower-overhead write) when stdout is going somewhere other than a tty, but `echo` is not such a command.

Comment: The cause was actually much simpler. I forgot to adjust the redirection on the source, which is in fact not needed at all using `exec` to redirect. See explanation in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67839242/incomplete-redirection-of-stdout-and-stderr-using-exec

Answer (score 2):

The `{} > ...` construct tries running the code in `{}` after `> ...`. Bash needs to know the output redirection before running the command(s).
Have you tried setting `stdout_file` and `stderr_file` before the code that you want the output of redirected?

That is, your code should be:

```
stdout_file="/some/path/$1/timestamp.stdout"         # Creating job-id specific folders
stderr_file="/some/path/$1/timestamp.stderr"
{
   # ...content subject to redirections here...
} >"$stdout_file" 2>"$stderr_file"
```

You may also find `>&1`, `2>&2` useful, rather than passing in folders.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've updated my answer to be authoritative. I can't comment on questions yet, and without definitively knowing that what I am saying is correct I default to guessing. Thank you for confirming :)

Comment: BTW, I'm not quite sure what you mean re: `>&1` or `2>&2` -- both those operations make a file descriptor a copy of its prior value, and thus have no effect at all.

Comment: I meant `>&1 2>&2` to be used for the redirection of the `actual_script.sh` output. So the full command could be run with, for example: `./generic_wrapper.sh > ./stdout.log 2> ./stderr.log`. But I see that the OP wanted to add some additional information to the filename, like timestamp, so it may be redundant.

Comment: Sure. That said, I assume that when the OP says "timestamp.stdout", their real use case is something more like `$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S).stdout`. They'd need a separate shell script as a wrapper to automate that, so it's reasonable to want to do it internally.