# How can I stop printing Terminal in Swift

Tags: swift, bash, shell, terminal

I want make this below code works for Swift, the codes works okay without `/dev/null 2>&1`, as soon as I add `/dev/null 2>&1`, it does not work, how can I add it correctly?

```
let task = Process()
task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/bash/dev/null 2>&1")
task.arguments = ["-c", """
                    echo "Hello, world!"
                    cd ${HOME}
                    cd Desktop
                    mkdir "New Folder"
                    echo "Folder is Successfully created!"
                    """]
task.launch()
```

Comment: It's unclear. `2>&1` means put error output (stderr) in normal output (stdout). So how could ""/bin/bash/dev/null 2>&1"" be a file path? If In `task`, if you don't read the output, what about checking the output, but not print it? Same for error one.

Comment: @Larme: I am not advanced in Bash, but as far as I now `2>&1` should mute error in case. Also as I mentioned in my question, I am asking the correct way of use case, I just add it by myself. Need to learn the right way plz.

Comment: @ioscoder Is the script you have here just an example script, or are you actually looking to create a new directory at `$HOME/New Folder`? Because if it's the latter, you don't need to be using `Process` or `bash` for this at all: [`FileManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816981/how-can-i-stop-printing-terminal-in-swift) would be the right way to do that.

Comment: @ItaiFerber: thanks a lot, but I want it for bash purpose in swift. There is some time I want mute print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main issues here:

1. The executable URL to the binary you'd like to run needs to point to the binary — it can't take arguments, because `/bin/bash/dev/null 2>&1` is not a valid path on disk. If you want to run `/bin/bash`, the executable URL can only contain `/bin/bash`
2. The redirection you're trying to perform isn't written out quite correctly either. Briefly:

   - `2>&1` in `bash` means "please point `stderr` (`2`) to where `stdout` (`1`) is currently pointing"
   - In order to redirect `stdout` first, it's not enough to just specify `/dev/null` — you need to tell `bash` "please point `stdout` to `/dev/null`", which is done with the shorthand `>/dev/null` (note the leading `>` meaning "redirection")

The syntax for these redirections is part of the actual *shell* you're running, and although `bash` might understand `>/dev/null`, this won't work for all processes.

One way you can request this redirection of `bash` is to include the redirection request inside of the shell script you're running (i.e., what you pass in to `-c`). This starts getting into the specifics of `bash` and how it handles redirections, but an example of how to achieve this:

```swift
task.arguments = ["-c", """
                        exec >/dev/null 2>&1
                        # The rest of your script.
                        """]
```

That `exec` line causes `bash` to effect the redirection, and it remains active for the rest of the script. Explaining the specifics might be out of scope, but check out [How to redirect output of an entire shell script within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314675/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-entire-shell-script-within-the-script-itself) for more information.

#### However:

Instead of this `bash`-specific approach, a less fragile and more expressive way to achieve exactly this is to explicitly set the `.standardOutput` and `.standardError` properties on the `Process` itself. You can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` from outside of `bash` altogether with the following:

```swift
let task = Process()
task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/bash")
task.arguments = ["-c", "..."]
task.standardOutput = FileHandle.nullDevice // Equivalent to /dev/null
task.standardError = FileHandle.nullDevice
task.launch()
```

[`.standardInput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1411576-standardinput), [`.standardOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1407627-standardoutput), and [`.standardError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1414916-standarderror) on a `Process` help direct where the process's input comes from, and where its output goes. By default, those are *inherited* from your current process (which is why you're even seeing `bash`'s output in your own output to begin with), but you can assign a `FileHandle` to write the output to a file, or set a `Pipe` to be able to read the output directly.

The above redirection will work for any process, not just `bash`, and it's recommended you use these semantic properties over relying on `bash` parsing.

---

If you don't care about redirecting to `/dev/null` specifically, you can alternatively *close* the process's `stdout` and `stderr` by passing in `nil` instead of `FileHandle.nullDevice`:

```swift
task.standardOutput = nil
task.standardError = nil
```

For this specific application, this assignment will have the same effect as redirecting to `/dev/null`: output from your script will be silenced.

There is *technically* a difference between these (if the script were inspecting where its `stdout` and `stderr` were being output to), but in the most common use cases, this would be equivalent. Consider using this as a "simplification" over referring to `FileHandle.nullDevice` directly.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but the code in first block about `task.arguments = [">/dev/null", "2>&1", "-c", "..."]` does not help much Swift error: `/bin/bash: >/dev/null: No such file or directory`

Comment: @ioscoder On my machine it appears to work, but intermittently. I would highly recommend using `.standardOutput` and `.standardError`, and I think I'll remove that initial suggestion altogether.

Comment: Your answer solve my issue, how ever I wanted to learn how i can use  `/dev/null 2>&1` correctly with swift.

Comment: @ioscoder I'll update my answer to include a bit more information, but the short of it is that "you can't", with that syntax. Specifically, `>/dev/null` and `2>&1` are not Swift syntax, but `bash` syntax; you need to pass those in in a way that `bash` itself understands, because those don't mean anything to Swift. One alternative way is passing `exec >/dev/null 2>&1` as a command at the very top of your script (right after `"""`) — this will cause `bash` to execute that redirection inside of the script itself.

Comment: @ioscoder For more info on that approach, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314675/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-entire-shell-script-within-the-script-itself might help with some specifics.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use `exec >/dev/null 2>&1`, your answer is completely solved my issue I just needed more learning how could I use  `>/dev/null 2>&1`, update: I just tried and it works, thanks again. :)