# How to use a variable from a block of code in the filename the output is redirected to?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script of which I want to capture the output using a [block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315113/1256347) ([docs](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#CODEBLOCKREF)).

Additionally I want to use the value of a variable from that block of code in the filename I write the output to, unfortunately that is not working.

How can I re-use the variable from a block of code in the filename?

#### Minimum example

This is a dummy script showing what I'm trying to do. I have `GNU bash, version 5.0.17`:

```bash
{
    v=1
    echo $v
} >> output-$v.log 2>&1
```

I set a variable, run some command and want to store the stdout and stderr in a file that has the variable in it's name (`output-1.log` in this case).

However, this writes out a file `output-.log` as if the `$v` variable does not exist.

#### What I've tried

If I add a semicolon `;` after the block of code:

```bash
{
    v=1
    echo $v
}; >> output-$v.log 2>&1
```

The file `output-1.log` is created, but it remains empty

Comment: The redirection must be set up by the shell before the program is run. Therefore you need to set `v` in a previous statement, outside of your code block.

Comment: Thanks! If I move `v=1` before the block of code it works. If the redirection is set-up before the program, why does the variable propagate to the filename correctly when I run it with the semicolon (ignoring for a moment that the file remains empty)?

Comment: It does not. The semicolon terminates the code block (which is simply not redirected), and then you have an empty command consisting only of redirection. `; >output-1.log` creates an empty logfile.

Comment: Alright, I see. Thanks again! Feel free to make your first comment an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the variable before setting up the redirection:

```
v=1
{
  echo $v
} >> output-$v.log 2>&1
```